# custom style for links inside <div> not working

Tags: html, css

I am stuck on something that seems very simple but I must be missing some minor detail.
I have this div:

```
<div id="menu" class="menu_div">
<a href="/">HOME</a> | 
<a href="/pics.php">PICTURES</a>
</div>
```

And the following inside the style tags

```
.menu_div {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid black;
    width: 900px;
    a:link {color:#000000; text-decoration:none;}      /* unvisited link */
    a:visited {color:#000000; text-decoration:none;}  /* visited link */
    a:hover {color:#FF0000; text-decoration:none;}  /* mouse over link */
    a:active {color:#FF0000; text-decoration:none;}  /* selected link */
}
```

Everything works except the links. I tried other combinations like .menu_div a:hover etc, nothing seems to work, any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Is that LESS/SASS or proper CSS?  If it's proper CSS, you have to move the link rules outside the .menu_div rule: 
    `.menu_div { ... }`
    `.menu_div a { color: #000; text-decoration: none; }`
    `.menu-div a:hover, .menu-div a:active { color: #f00; }` 
if it's LESS/SASS, make sure you're compiling down to CSS.  Also, have you tried using your browser's Inspector/Developer Tools at all?

Comment: agree with tuba, also if it still doesn't work.  Try targeting #menu in case something else is overriding

Comment: A menu is a list of links, it should be expressed as such. See [listmatic](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/) for lots of examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any SASS or LESS tags, so here is the solution - you can't have nested rules in CSS. You must define them separately:

```css
.menu_div {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid black;
    width: 900px;
}

.menu_div a:link {color:#000000; text-decoration:none;}      /* unvisited link */
.menu_div a:visited {color:#000000; text-decoration:none;}   /* visited link */
.menu_div a:hover {color:#FF0000; text-decoration:none;}     /* mouse over link */
.menu_div a:active {color:#FF0000; text-decoration:none;}    /* selected link */
```

Comment: That will select all links, not just those inside the div.

Comment: @Quentin True. But I don't see anywhere in the question that the OP is trying to apply these rule *only* to the menu links

Comment: Sorry - my bad, just noticed

Answer (score 2):

You can't nest rulesets in CSS. You have to use [descendant combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators).

```
.menu_div {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid black;
    width: 900px;
}

.menu_div a:link {color:#000000; text-decoration:none;}      /* unvisited link */
.menu_div a:visited {color:#000000; text-decoration:none;}  /* visited link */
.menu_div a:hover {color:#FF0000; text-decoration:none;}  /* mouse over link */
.menu_div a:active {color:#FF0000; text-decoration:none;}  /* selected link */
```

Comment: Ohh, didn't know that. Thanks! It works now. Will accept the answer as soon as i'm allowed